# Propel join query not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, propel

I am new to propel and i have implemented it with codeigniter. Below i have submitted the query along with the join. As per the query, i am creating a join with two tables i.e "**items**" and "**itemsfields**".

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(itemspeer::ID, itemsfieldspeer::ITEM_ID);
$items = itemspeer::doSelect($c);
```

But as i executed this query. I found that it returns only items data. Please help me to create join with these two tables.

Comment: What version of Propel are you using? The newer (and much more flexible) approach is to use the `Query` objects for each table. Using `Criteria` was deprecated in 1.4 I think, and is removed for 2.0. The current stable version is 1.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

In addJoin, mention

> CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN

or which ever join.

Comment: I used CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN but i did't got the expected result.

Comment: by expected results you mean join did not happen ?

Comment: try [this](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#joining-tables) link, may be you can get some more ideas about joining tables